# Mongodb golang aggregate group by retrieving the multiple values of _id

Tags: mongodb, go

How to get values of group by field A and field B which are party of _id group by

If I print values using []bson.M passing to cursor.All() it shows _id values as map

But decoding struct values, _id returns [], how to parse the values

```
    type MyStruct struct {
        _id map[string]interface{}
        Total int           
    }

    pipeline := []bson.M{bson.M{ "$match": bson.M{ "A": "xyz" } }, bson.M{ "$group": bson.M{ "_id": bson.M{"A": "$A", "B": "$B"}, "Total": bson.M{ "$sum": 1}}}}

    showInfoCursor, err := entityCollection.Aggregate(mongoContext, pipeline)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for showInfoCursor.Next(mongoContext) {
        entity := new(MyStruct)
        err := cur.Decode(entity)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error reading cursor : %s\n", err)      
        }

        fmt.Printf("Entity Value - %s\n", entity)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$project can be used to get required values.

Example:

```
bson.M {
    "$project": bson.M {
        "A": "$_id.A",
        "B": "$_id.B",
        "Total": 1
    }
}
```